# Arduino WiFi101 Library - Pass WiFi and WiFiClient to child classes

Tags: c++, c, pointers, arduino

I’m slowly getting to work on an IoT project involving a WiFi client using the Adafruit ItsyBitsy M4, ATWINC1500 and WiFi101 library. All works great when in a single sketch, but this is quickly becoming unmanageably long. I've switched to a PlatformIO environment and am rewriting using CPP.

I want to be able to modularise my code by its purpose into classes which for the most part has been successful. I can then pass pointers (`*`) of the connected hardware (i.e. NeoPixel and Uart for serial ports) to the classes "set" method. Though, I have been unable to do this with the `WiFiClass` and `WiFiClient` classes.

I’ve had a go at passing the `WiFi` and `WiFiClient` to my classes as a pointer (see code below), in the same way I have successfully done it with Uart Classe for my serial ports (though I have to use `->` and not `.` for methods). The issue is, whilst I am able to determine (what I believe to be) the current client status, no data is ever returned in my loop(). I have getter and setter methods to get/set the `WiFiClient` pointer, yet there’s no data when I use them.

It also seems that `WiFiClass` (the `WiFi` object) is being automatically created when the sketch starts which makes me uncomfortable as I haven't declared it anywhere.

### My questions:

1. Is there any way to explicitly declare a `WiFiClass` and initialise a custom WiFi101 connection, as opposed to using the default `WiFi` class provided by the library? For clarity I like to see where things are initialised and not just accept that they have been.
2. Is it actually possible for me to pass the `WiFiClient` class through to my own classes and have all classes use the same single instance back in `main.cpp` via pointers?

Below is what I have tried so far:

#### NetworkInterface class

(originally designed to hold the entire instantiated WiFi class, but currently just using WiFiClient):

```
// network-interface.cpp:

WiFiClient NetworkInterface::getNetworkClient() {
    return *_networkClient;
}

byte NetworkInterface::setNetworkInterface(WiFiClient *newNetworkInterface, interfacetype_t mode) {
    if (mode >= 0 && mode <= 3) {
        networkMode = mode;
    } else {
        networkMode = -1; // TODO: Use enum
        return -1;
    }
    _networkClient = newNetworkInterface;
    return mode;
}


// .header file:

#ifndef NETWORKINTERFACE_H
#define NETWORKINTERFACE_H_

#include "Arduino.h"

typedef enum {
  INTERFACETYPE_WIFI = 0,
  INTERFACETYPE_ETH = 1,
  INTERFACETYPE_BT = 2,
  INTERFACETYPE_UNSUPPORTED = -1
} interfacetype_t;

class NetworkInterface {

    public:
        bool connectToSSID(byte ssid[], byte password[]);
        bool getConnectionStatus();
        bool disconnectFromNetwork();
        interfacetype_t getNetworkMode();    
        WiFiClient getNetworkClient();
        byte setNetworkInterface(WiFiClient *newNetworkInterface, interfacetype_t mode);  // 26.01.2019 - LIMITED TO WiFICLIENT, UNSURE ABOUT WiFiClass

    private:
        interfacetype_t networkMode;
        WiFiClient *_networkClient;
};

#endif
```

#### main class:

```
// main.cpp:

#include <SPI.h>
#include <WiFi101.h>
#include "arduino_secrets.h"
#include "network-interface.h"

char ssid[] = SECRET_SSID;        // your network SSID (name)
char pass[] = SECRET_PASS;    // your network password (use for WPA, or use as key for WEP)
int keyIndex = 0;            // your network key Index number (needed only for WEP)
int status = WL_IDLE_STATUS;
char server[] = "www.google.com";    // name address for Google (using DNS)
WiFiClient client;

NetworkInterface networkInterface;


void setup() {
    //Initialize serial and wait for port to open:
    Serial.begin(9600);
    while (!Serial);

    Serial.println("= = = Simple Client-Server Test = = = ");

    WiFi.setPins(A5, A4, A3, A2);
    if (WiFi.status() == WL_NO_SHIELD) {
        Serial.println("WiFi shield not present");
        while (true);
    }

    // attempt to connect to WiFi network:
    while (status != WL_CONNECTED) {
        Serial.print("Attempting to connect to SSID: ");
        Serial.println(ssid);
        // Connect to WPA/WPA2 network. Change this line if using open or WEP network:
        status = WiFi.begin(ssid, pass);

        // wait for connection 
        delay(2000);
    }
    Serial.println("Connected to wifi");
    printWiFiStatus();

    Serial.println("\nStarting connection to server...");

    /*
      Pass the network client (and hopefully soon WiFi class with hardware connection data) to NetworkInterface class

      TODO: IMPLEMENT ENUM FOR INTERFACE TYPES
    */
    networkInterface.setNetworkInterface(&client, 0); 
    ...
}

void loop() {
    // if there are incoming bytes available
    // from the server, read them and print them:
    WiFiClient myClient = networkInterface.getNetworkClient();

    if (myClient.available()) {
        Serial.print("\n==================================\n");
        Serial.print("| REMOTE :: Server Has Responded: |");
        Serial.print("\n----------------------------------\n");
        while (myClient.available()) {
            char c = myClient.read();
            Serial.write(c);
        }
        Serial.print("\n==================================\n");
    }

    // if the server's disconnected, stop the myClient:
    if (!myClient.connected()) {
        Serial.println();
        Serial.println("CLIENT :: Disconnecting");
        myClient.stop();

        // do nothing forevermore:
        while (true);
    }
}


void makeTestCallToPusher() {
      char serverURLTest[] = "192.168.2.4";

      WiFiClient myClient = networkInterface.getNetworkClient();

    if (myClient.connect(serverURLTest, 80)) {
        Serial.print("CLIENT :: Connected - ");Serial.print(serverURLTest);Serial.print("\n");
        myClient.println("GET /test HTTP/1.1");
        myClient.println("Upgrade: WebSocket");
        myClient.println("Connection: Upgrade");
        myClient.println("Origin: ARDUINO_TEST");
        myClient.println("Host: eu");
        myClient.println("Connection: close");
        myClient.println();
    }
}


void printWiFiStatus() {
    // print the SSID of the network you're attached to:
    Serial.print("SSID: ");
    Serial.println(WiFi.SSID());

    // print your WiFi shield's IP address:
    IPAddress ip = WiFi.localIP();
    Serial.print("IP Address: ");
    Serial.println(ip);

    // print the received signal strength:
    long rssi = WiFi.RSSI();
    Serial.print("signal strength (RSSI):");
    Serial.print(rssi);
    Serial.println(" dBm");
}
```

Answer (score 0):

`WiFi` is a global object declared in WiFi101.h and defined in WiFi.cpp (at the end of both files). To use it, include WiFi101.h or pass a reference to parameter or field of type `WiFiClass&` (reference to WiFiClass).

From your code it is not clear what you want to do with the client object. You have it global and I don't see where it connects to server. You set a pointer to the global object to the networkInterface object, store a pointer, but the getter function's return type is not a pointer and the local variable myClient isn't a pointer too.

If you want work with pointer, change the getter function to return a pointer. But then the original object must exist somewhere (now it is global).

```
WiFiClient* myClient = networkInterface.getNetworkClient();
if (myClient->available()) {
```

But the WiFiClient class is only a wrapper and has the `=` operator overloaded as copy. If copied it still refers the same underlying TCP socket. So you can assign it without pointer or reference.

```
WiFiClient _networkClient;
byte setNetworkInterface(WiFiClient &client) {
  _networkClient = client; // copy data about TCP socket
}
```

Comment: Hi Juraj, thank you for taking the time to explain. The code I provided isn’t clear and I’ve introduced mistakes from trying different things. I should’ve checked properly first. I’m currently writing a client library to “talk” with Pusher Channels which will eventually use the client. I just thought I’d try passing it to some kind of class first. Will implement what you have suggested later today